# Warning: Ignoring extra legend entries.

Tags: matlab-figure, legend, legend-properties

I am creating several plots. Each plot can have up to 5 lines. At the end of my code I am including the line:

```
legend([line0 line1 line2 line3 line4],{'DN','D','R','ME','PP'})
```

However, sometimes some of the lines (line0 to line4) have no points on them, and therefore matlab gives an error saying:

```
Warning: Ignoring extra legend entries.
```

Although the lines have no points, I still want matlab to include them on the legend. 
Any workaround for this?
Please let me know if anything is not clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just found the answer. 
I just need to replace the empty vectors with NaN and the legend entry will show up.
Thanks!